# Unable to get property 'srcElement' of undefined or null reference OR window.event is undefined in FF

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, lync-2013

I have implemented a Lync Contact Card Presence as follows:

```
var email = "userEmail@example.com";
var uuid = guid() + ",type=sip";
IMNRC(email, document.getElementById(uuid));
function guid() {  function s4() { return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1); }
return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4(); }
```

In IE 10 and above it works sometimes, sometimes it throws "Unable to get property 'srcElement' of undefined or null reference".

In FireFox, it throws "window.event is undefined in FF"

I tried to use the following code but it didn't work:

```
document.addEventListener('onclick',ex.exampl,true);

var ex = { exampl: function(e){ var evt = e || window.event } }
```

Comment: `document.addEventListener('onclick',ex.exampl,true);` should be `document.addEventListener('click',ex.exampl,true);`

Comment: Unable to get property 'exampl' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Well you need to define the object before you reference it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be "click" not "onclick". You need to defined the object before you reference it because of hoisting. And you show an error about srcElement, but there is no srcElement in your code.

```js
var ex = {
  exampl: function(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event,
        target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    console.log(target);
  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', ex.exampl, true);
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

In modern browsers, you really do not need the window check.

Comment: I have followed your answer and in IE got it working however in FF still the same, dont know what is wrong.

Comment: About srcElement, I wonder the same, I have not used it anywehere however it throws the error.

Comment: @user  .srcElement is the obsolete IE equivalent of .target property.  see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974945(v=vs.85).aspx   ---  when FF doesn't like compound object.property as listener functiion, you can wrap it like this:  function(evt){ ex.exampl(evt) }

Comment: Clear your cache on firefox.

Comment: target = e.target || _evt_.srcElement